# How is a command following the while command executed over the loops?

Tags: bash

1. In `while <command>` part of a while loop, is `<command>` executed
   in each loop independently of other loops?
2. In the following example, why can the while loop make `read` read
   all the lines of a file one by one, while without the while loop,
   `read` always read the first line of the file in every repetition?

   Without using the while loop, can `read` read all the lines of the
   file one by one?

   ```
   $ cat /tmp/tt
   1 2 3 4 5
   6 7 8 9
   10 11

   $ cat /tmp/tt | while read tt; do echo $tt; done
   1 2 3 4 5
   6 7 8 9
   10 11

   $ cat /tmp/tt | read tt
   $ echo $tt
   1 2 3 4 5
   $ cat /tmp/tt | read tt
   $ echo $tt
   1 2 3 4 5
   ```

Comment: man read: 'The read utility shall read a single line from standard input.'. Regarding your experiments, first try clear out the variable tt, it seems to me tt has a value set already. The way you read tt from a pipe and echoing tt as a separete command, should result in a empty string, because piped commands execute in their own subshell, the variable value is lost after the pipe exits. While loop should work because you are echoing the variable from within the subshell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have two command-lines with two `read` instances of `cat` outputs, then only the first line can be read, in the way you have used, because STDIN for `read` will always have the same contents with the same first line.

If you read the contents of one cat output multiple times, you will get the next lines, because STDIN for read will not get reset to original starting line.

```
$ cat /tmp/tt | ( read tt ; echo $tt )
1 2 3 4 5

$ cat /tmp/tt | ( read tt ; echo $tt ; read tt ; echo $tt )
1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9

$ cat /tmp/tt | ( read tt ; echo $tt ; read tt ; echo $tt ; read tt ; echo $tt )
1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9
10 11
```

In short : "(A) If you execute `read` once, twice & thrice on the same input (STDIN), you will get the first second & third lines. (B) If you `read` many times, but reset the input for every `read`, then you will only get the same first line many times"

More Info : By "grouping" the `read` instances (on the left of the pipe), the sub-shell keeps the pipe open. When using `while`, again the sub-shell keeps the pipe open. Hence, `read` will read the "next line" every time, rather than the "first line".

Comment: thanks. Is it right that the commands in pipeline run in subshells, and the grouping of the `read` and `echo` commands further run in subshells of the subshells?

Comment: Correct, sub-shell handles the pipe. in the pipe there may be commands which run as child-processes of the sub-shell.

Comment: I am not just talking about subprocess of the subshell for pipe. Grouped commands by parenthese also create subshells for the commands to run in.  So  is the following hierarchy of processes correct: the shell process where you run the commands with the pipe -> the subshell process for the pipe -> the subshell by parentheses group -> the subprocesses for read and for echo?

Comment: Correct !! Reference : http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/subshells.html for more about sub-shells.

Answer (score 3):

#### Q1

> In `while` `<command>` part of a while loop, is `<command>` executed in each loop independently of other loops?

Yes, `<command>` will be executed for each loop of the `while` loop executed.

How many loops are executed is affected by other loops if other loops also consume the `stdin` input. The `read` command reads from stdin (unles option `-u n` is used). Some other read may consume the same input, that will affect the *first* `while` loop.

#### Q2

A new code, as yours has a big fault <sup>[1]</sup>.

```
$ cat /tmp/tt | {  read tt; echo "$tt";   }
1 2 3 4 5
$ cat /tmp/tt | {  read tt; echo "$tt";   }
1 2 3 4 5
```

The `cat` command will always start at the beginning of a file.
The `read` command (without the `-d` option set to something else from `new line` (`$'\n'`)) will get the first line and will **exit (causing the pipe to close)**.

In a `while` loop even if read exists, there is still code to be executed (the while) **that will keep the pipe open** to get the next line from the `cat` command.

> ```
> $ cat /tmp/tt | while read tt; do echo $tt; done
> 1 2 3 4 5
> 6 7 8 9
> 10 11
> ```

<sup>[1] your code must clean `$tt`, try `unset tt; cat /tmp/tt |{ read tt; echo "$tt"; }` to confirm.</sup>